# Webpack error while importing an image url as background in css

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, sass

I am adding a background image to my section in my scss file. The linear gradient is to darken the image. The url is correct and I am sure of it.

```
    background-image: url(../../assets/img/hero-bg.jpg),
        linear-gradient(rgba(black, 0.3), rgba(black, 0.3));
    height: 1980px;
```

I am getting the following error -

```
ERROR in ./src/sass/main.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/sass/main.scss)
```

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):

Images through html are loading fine.
This is my webpack config -

```
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/i,
            use: [ 'style-loader',
                'css-loader',
                'sass-loader',
            ],
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/i,
            use: ['html-loader'],
        },
        {
            test: /\.(svg|jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$/i,
            use: {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
                    publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '/assets/img'),
                    outputPath: 'assets/img',
                },
            },
        }
    ],

plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name].css',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: '/src/template.html',
    }),
],
```

Could someone solve this?

Answer (score 2):

There's no `sourceMap` option for `style-loader`, either set it for `css-loader` or `sass-loader` as per https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#sourcemap.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however I realised my mistake earlier and removed it. It has still not fixed my problem

Comment: Then update your post so we can see what's going on.

Comment: I saw you only update your configuration here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64989401/revisions, which doesn't make sense if you still have that same error.

Comment: I have updated the error earlier? Arent you able to see that?

Comment: Will removing your `background-image` fix the error? If yes, then there might be something wrong with it.

Comment: Yah it fixes it. However, I want to be able to use images in my css.